# How to plot 3D graphs in C?

Tags: c, opencv

I am working on a project which involves stereo-vision. I am using c and openncv right now. I want to make a 3D plot of points based on their calculated position. Can someone tell how to do it in c or opencv?

platform: XP, visualstudio 2005

Comment: Why not just use an existing library like gnuplot?

Comment: you may be right but I even dont know if something like that exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 3D rendering engine like OpenGL or DirectX. You can use any of them in VS2005 and WindowsXP.